# Problem involving parallelograms

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

$ABCD$ is a parallelogram in which $\frac{AB}{BC} = \lambda $. If $P$, $Q$ are points on the line $CD$ with $P$ on $CD$ and $M$ is a point $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle PAQ$ and $AM$ bisects $\angle PAB$, $BM = a$, $DQ = b$, prove that $AQ = \frac{a}{\lambda + b} $.

I have tried to use the fact that $\frac{AB}{BC} = \lambda$ by constructing the internal angle bisector of $\angle B$ meeting $AC$ at $O$, but could not proceed much further after that.

Comment: Your relation $a/(\lambda+b)$ makes no sense, as $\lambda$ is a ratio whereas $a$ and $b$ are lengths.

Comment: If that's the case then maybe the question was printed wrong. I'm sorry, I just copied the question from a textbook of mine.

Comment: I think it should be "prove that $AQ = a/\lambda + b$". You probably misread the text.

Comment: Well, I ran through the problem once more. I clearly did not misread it. Maybe, there's some print error. That's not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an answer but a query instead. I try to draw a special case of it by letting (1) $\lambda = 1$; and (2) AB = AP = AM.

[image]

Clearly, $a \lt 1$ and $\dfrac {a}{\lambda + b} = \dfrac {a}{1 + b}$is a quantity less than 1 but the picture shows AQ is a line much longer than 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: See my comment to the question. Changing length units your result will change.